# Add a class to a DIV when top of the window reach a specific element and remove it when not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `.navigation` in the top of the wrapper.
I want to add it a `.fixed` class, when the top of the window reached the `.bottom` DIV & remove this class when the top of the `.bottom` is in the window`s scope (it's a toggling between add and remove .fixed class).

[image: add fixed class to the navigation]

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
        <!-- There are some list elements here -->
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

It's what I made, but not work

```
bottom     = $('.bottom');
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > bottom){ 
        $('.navigation').addClass('fixed'); 
    }
    else{
        $('.navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Visualising your requirement is nice, But where's your code.?

Comment: How is the `.navigation` being scrolled?

Comment: @acdcjunior It's scrolled with the default browser scroller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var bottom = $('.bottom').offset().top;`

That should do it.

This compares the offset from the top of the viewport to the window's `scrollTop()` instead of comparing a whole element.